# DefaultHttpClient blocking different threads

Tags: android, multithreading, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a Android app with a background service that sends info to an HTTP server. In the foreground I have a `Activity` that fetches info for the UI. Both use a `doSending` class that is inherited from `AsyncTask` to do the actual communication.

In this `doSending` class, I instantiate a `DefaultHttpClient` to run the communications. However, it seems like the "foreground" communication (triggered by the user) is blocked by the "background" communication (triggered by a timer).

```
private class doSending extends AsyncTask<Telegram, Integer, Long> {
    [..]
    @Override 
    protected Long doInBackground(Telegram... telegrams) {
       [..]
       HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
       [..]
       c.execute();
    }
    [..]
}
```

called like this:

```
Telegram t = new Telegram();
new doSending().execute(t);
```

Is it true that `DefaultHttpClient` can only have one connection at the time, app-wide? And if so, how do I make this multi-connected?

Comment: Are you sure it's the HttpClient and not the AsyncTask that can only have one running instance? If I recall correctly, the default threadpool for AsyncTask (unfortunately) has 1 thread associated with it which means only 1 active AsyncTask can run at any given time.

Comment: @kha I am not sure. It could certainly also be the AsyncTask pool. Could I set that higher? Just checked, and it could very well be the AsyncTask yes.

Comment: You can try this: `asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);` Have a look at this link for reference: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html specially this sentence: `If your android:targetSdkVersion is set to 13 or higher, and you are running on Android 4.x or higher, AsyncTask will use an Executor that executes only one task at a time`

Comment: @kha, that fixed it. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Try this it will process your task parallel asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure it's the HttpClient and not the AsyncTask that can only have one running instance? If I recall correctly, the default threadpool for AsyncTask (unfortunately) has 1 thread associated with it which means only 1 active AsyncTask can run at any given time.

To fix, you can try this:

```
asyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, params);
```

Have a look at this link for reference: http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/04/20/asynctask-threading-regression-confirmed.html

specially this sentence: `If your android:targetSdkVersion is set to 13 or higher, and you are running on Android 4.x or higher, AsyncTask will use an Executor that executes only one task at a time`.